# Rails Mailer - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want an email to be sent to the user when another user deletes an object related to the original user. But right now I get this error: `` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass `` with `@agreement = params[:agreement]` highlighted (below full code). Basically I'm trying to send email before the object is deleted.

My mailer

```rb
    def agreement_delete
        @agreement = params[:agreement]
        @sent_user = User.find(@agreement.user_id)
        @user = User.find(@agreement.thought.user_id)
        @user_email = @user.email

        mail(to: @user_email, subject: "It's been deleted!")
    end
```

My agreement controller

```rb
    def destroy
        @agreement = Agreement.find(params[:id])
        UserMailer.with(agreement: @agreement).agreement_delete.deliver_later
        @agreement.destroy
        redirect_back 
    end
```

My agreement.rb

```rb
  before_destroy :check_delete

  private
  def check_delete
        UserMailer.agreement_delete.deliver
  end
```

I'd think there is something wrong with `params[:agreement]`, but mailer that sends email upon creation of agreement works just fine, and that one has same `@agreement = params[:agreement]`. I'd really appreciate help.

By the way, email does get sent. Just that the application breaks because of the error.

Comment: Mailers aren't a controller, they don't have `params`. You'll need to supply any required parameters as arguments, like `agreement_delete(@agreement)`.

Comment: Note you may be shooting yourself in the foot here by queueing up a job for a thing you go ahead and destroy before that job can run. If that argument is captured properly in the job maybe you're fine, but you may want to extract specific values instead, like just the name or other details necessary to render the email.

Comment: @tadman Thank you for your reply. That was my confusion -- as I wrote, "I'd think there is something wrong with ```params[:agreement]```, but mailer that sends email upon creation of agreement works just fine, and that one has same ``` @agreement = params[:agreement]. ```" But reading your second comment got me thinking -- perhaps the error is showing because the object is deleted? And perhaps the email still got sent because it was happening somehow at the same time? Well, still very confused.

Comment: I see now you're using the `with(...)` style. What style does your creation method use?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if those arguments are serialized into the job as-is, or it's just saved as a reference to a database record that's later reloaded. You can probably observe what happens by watching `log/development.log`.

Comment: What version of Ruby on Rails are you using?

Comment: @tadman the creation method uses the same with(...).

Comment: @spickermann I'm using Rails 7 and Ruby 3.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your agreement controller

```
def destroy
    @agreement = Agreement.find(params[:id])
    # you can't deliver_later, the object will be gone.
    UserMailer.agreement_delete(@agreement).deliver_now
    @agreement.destroy
    redirect_back 
end
```

Your mailer

```
def agreement_delete(agreement)
    # bring in the information you need, in this case: an agreement record
    @agreement = agreement
    @sent_user = User.find(@agreement.user_id)
    @user = User.find(@agreement.thought.user_id)
    @user_email = @user.email

    mail(to: @user_email, subject: "It's been deleted!")
end
```

Your agreement.rb

```
  before_destroy :check_delete

  private
  def check_delete
    # the email is being sent twice?
    # Once from the controller, and once from the model? Why?
    # UserMailer.agreement_delete(self).deliver
  end
```

In the comments, you say `params[]` are somehow available to other mailers. Weird and unexpected. You shouldn't rely on that. It's a better, safer practice to give your methods the information they need and only the information they need.

If you really want to `.deliver_later`, I'd suggest a different pattern:

the `#destroy` action should call a Job that can `.perform_later`.
The Job should send the email, THEN delete the record.